# Without using the mouse, how can I move the cursor/focus from left buffer (window) to the right window in the user settings view

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently an emacs/vi user (spacemacs) I'm trying vscode, in my workflow I don't use the mouse, I'm wondering how can I move my cursor to the right in this view?
[image: user settings view]

Answer (score 1):

If your question is specific to the user settings view, these are the steps I would follow:

1. Search for what you want in the `Search Settings` bar
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once and you will be able to switch between `User Settings` and `Workspace Settings`. You can use the <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> arrow keys to select between them if you want.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again till you go to the left-hand side settings panel
4. Copy the settings you want, Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to go to the right-hand side panel
5. When you are done with that panel, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Here's a screen recording to demonstrate the above steps:

[image: Check my demo here]

However, you would be using multiple panes during development. Let say you have two panels on the left and right side. You can switch between them by following the below keys:

- Left Panel : Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- Right Panel : Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

This would work up to 3 panels as specifically said by [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_side-by-side-editing)

> When you have more than one editor open you can switch between them
>   quickly by holding the Ctrl (Mac: 'Cmd') key and pressing 1, 2, or 3.

I would be happy to update my answer if you have more questions.

PS - I will update this for Mac users soon

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed answer.
It seems it's more complicated that I was expecting.
So, this user's settings window is a special case.
I'm coming from the emacs world where everything is a buffer, but apparently, this doesn't apply to vscode.
Thanks again

Comment: I'm afraid the same behaviour couldn't be mimicked in VSCode even though I tried several plugins which have emacs keybindings written for VSCode. Some are literally broken. Although I believe a panel in VSCode has the same idea behind emacs' buffers, Settings panel seems a special case. Anyway, once you get the hang of Ctrl+1 .. 3 It would be easier for you to navigate through panels :)

Comment: I have same request for that by switching windows `ctrl + w + left` in vim-keymap